# How to solve "command \f already defined" error when running ling-macros package

Tags: xetex, errors, packages, linguistics

I'm typesetting my paper (linguistics) and it ran fine in XeLaTeX until I used the `ling-macros` package, which should have been working fine, given it's not a new package and I've found no similar questions about the error I encountered. This is what I got:

```
    > ! LaTeX Error: Command \f already defined.
    >                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
    > 
    > See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
    > <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
    > 
    >                                                    l.235 \newcommand{\f}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
    >                                           ^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I% Formal express...
    > 
    > ?
```

I'm sure it's somehow to do with `ling-macros` (or with its conflict with some other packages I used?) since that's a very specific message I got; when I %'ed that line the file ran fine again (see last line below).

The following is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{4ex}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespace
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[rm, bf]{titlesec} % formatting taken out for brevity

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % actual header taken out
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{titling} % actual title with author info taken out

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{ling-macros}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `linguex` package defines `\f` as an alias for `\b`. Also `\b` is given a different meaning than in standard LaTeX (which is the “underbar” accent).

In the context of `linguex`, inside `\ex.` one inputs `\a.` and `\b.` for introducing items. The package also provides `\c. \d. \e. \f.` for more items.

You can work around the issue in two ways. One is quite drastic, namely to remove the possibility of using `\f.` for items inside `\ex.`:  just add `\let\f\relax` before `\usepackage{ling-macros}`.

If you want to use `\f.` for items inside `\ex.`, you need a more elaborate trick, shown below.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% packages

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[rm, bf]{titlesec} % formatting taken out for brevity
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % actual header taken out
\usepackage{titling} % actual title with author info taken out

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

%% fix the issues with \f
\let\f\relax % remove the definition done by linguex
\usepackage{ling-macros} % load the package
\makeatletter
\let\lingmacros@f\f
\DeclareRobustCommand{\f}{\@ifnextchar.\b\lingmacros@f}
\makeatother

%% settings

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\doublespacing % not \doublespace
% you don't know what ex is, until at begin document
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\parindent{4ex}}
% leave a little flexibility to \parskip
%\setlength\parskip{0pt}
```

I separated the package loading part from the settings part. Note that `\doublespace` is not the right declaration, which should be `\doublespacing`.